# Vim howto insert a blank line before each change of pattern at the beginning of the lines?

Tags: regex, vim

Let us say I have a list such as :

```
Foo : 1st chapter
Foo : 2nd chapter
Bar : 1st chapter
Bar : 2nd chapter
Bar : 3rd chapter
Qux : 1st chapter
```

I want to insert a blank line (except before the first line, of course) each time a line begins with a different pattern (here 3 letters, but it could be 4-digit years : 2010, 2011, 2012, etc…) in order to have :

```
Foo : 1st chapter
Foo : 2nd chapter

Bar : 1st chapter
Bar : 2nd chapter
Bar : 3rd chapter

Qux : 1st chapter
```

How should I proceed ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:let x='Foo' | g/^/ let y=split(getline('.'))[0] | if x!=y | s/^/\r/ | let x=y | endif
```

**For simplicity:** You can `let x=''` then `:1d`

Comment: It works beautifully. But please explain 2 points : 1) if I write Foo, it will not insert a blank line at the beginning of the file ; on the other hand if I insert an altogether different pattern (e.g. Unix) it will insert a blank line at the beginning, while doing the job although there is no "Unix" in the list. 2) If I write "Foo", does it mean that the function will analyze the 3 first characters, and the 4 first characters if I write "Unix" ?

Comment: I use **`split(getline('.'))[0]`** to get first word of every line as a key to compare.

Answer (score 4):

In order to accomplish this task, one can use a single `:global` command
inserting a blank after every line that does not start with the same word as
the immediately following line:

```
:g/^\(\w\+\).*\n\1\@!./pu_
```

Comment: I am overwhelmed by riches : of course it works perfectly. Thank you very much. But now, a beginner's suggestion/request : how about a "solution forensics" to explain to beginners (but SO may not be for beginners) the pro and cons of different solutions allowed by (in that case) Vim ? So many roads lead to Rome...

Answer (score 1):

Awk to the rescue!

```
awk 'x != $1 { if(NR > 1)  print ""; x = $1 } {print}' file.txt > save-me.txt
```

Overview:

- `x != $1 { ... }` run the block when variable `x` does not equal the first field aka `$1`
- `if(NR > 1) print "";` print an blank space except on the first record.
- `x = $1` set `x` to be equal to the first field, `$1`
- `{print}` is shorthand for print the current record

You can filter text from Vim via a filter command like `:%!sort`. So to answer the proposed question you can do the following:

```
:%!awk 'x \!= $1 { if(NR > 1) print ""; x = $1 } {print}'
```

Overview:

- `%` is shorthand for a range of the whole file, aka `1,$`
- There is no filename in the example, that is because the lines represented by the range are being feed in via `stdin`.
- The output will replace the text in the range.
- You will have to escape any `!` with `\!`

See the following for more information on Vim's filtering

```
:h filter
:h :range!
:h :!
```

Comment: Thanks, it works very nicely ; but I would rather use kev's solution, for one simple reason : it allows me to stay in Vim to do the trick. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer AND for the explanations

Comment: I can get behind that. Just remember you can filter from vim like so: `%! awk 'x \!= $1 { if(NR > 1)  print ""; x = $1 } {print}'`. Just have make sure you escape your `!`.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer : this works exactly as I want. But how can I credit 2 persons (key and you) with an "accepted" answer ? Thanks again !

Comment: I tried it again and I have another question : if I have a succession of dates such as 2011.12.10, 2011.12.25, 2012.01.14, how must I proceed to insert a blank line between 2011 and 2012, but not between the different dates in 2011, i.e. how to make a difference based upon the first 4 characters ?

Comment: Awk defaults the field seperator to being whitespace. In your case you probably want to change the field seperator aka `FS` to `.`. You can do this as command line flag to awk via `-F.` So altogether `:%!awk -F. 'x \!= $1 { if(NR > 1) print ""; x = $1 } {print}'`

Comment: Very handy : and now I have to learn "Enough awk to be dangerous" (Classic Shell Scripting) ... Thanks a lot